# Play mp4 video in Matlab gui

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a **Matlab GUI**, on one side of it a video is playing and the other side has a button. On button click simply get playback time of video and store it in a file. Is there any way to play the video in a specified axis?  I am using following code but get no response.

```
xyloObj = VideoReader('xylophone.mp4');

vidWidth = xyloObj.Width;
vidHeight = xyloObj.Height;

mov = struct('cdata',zeros(vidHeight,vidWidth,3,'uint8'),...
    'colormap',[]);

k = 1;
while hasFrame(xyloObj)
    mov(k).cdata = readFrame(xyloObj);
    k = k+1;
end

hf = figure;
set(hf,'position',[150 150 vidWidth vidHeight]);

movie(hf,mov,1,xyloObj.FrameRate);
```

Comment: no response means what ? your getting error or video is not playing ?

Comment: This code is running perfectly but it play video in figure, I want to play video in gui axes. I replace hf = figure with hf = handle.axes1 after that only last frame of a video show in axes but i want to play complete video in gui axes.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will helpfull for you. Try it , if you have any problem with that or any queries related to that code just ask me

```
 xyloObj = VideoReader('xylophone.mpg');

    nFrames = xyloObj.NumberOfFrames;
    vidHeight = xyloObj.Height;
    vidWidth = xyloObj.Width;

    % Preallocate movie structure.
    mov(1:nFrames) = ...
        struct('cdata', zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, 3, 'uint8'),...
               'colormap', []);

    % Read one frame at a time.
    for k = 1 : nFrames
        mov(k).cdata = read(xyloObj, k);
    end        

    h = figure ; hf = axes('Parent' , h);


    % Play back the movie once at the video's frame rate.
    movie(hf, mov, 1, xyloObj.FrameRate);
```

Comment: Thanks brother for your reply. I find my issue I run above code within a callback of a button. And now the code run perfectly.

Comment: Your welcome bro . If above code is usefull for you then accepted as a answer by click the tick symbol or give vote for it .

Comment: Brother your code play video in a figure not in a GUI. The above code mean the code given in a question. The line of code hf = figure must be replace with hf = handle.axes1 to play video into Gui axes. But i really thankful to you for your answers. Thanks